# Windows 10 App : update taking long time

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I have submitted a second update of my application and its been two day, my app is in certification.where as, my first submission was passed within 2 hours.

App updates: resolved minor bugs and added a privacy policy criteria for ads. I have added **ads** in this update as well. I used **myapppolicy.com** site for making my privacy policy and added a link in the description while submitting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about a specific application and account in the App Store. It should be addressed to the vendor via email rather than posted here. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions, not general account support.

Comment: I am sorry, if you didn't like this question. But you could tell if the steps I have taken while giving update of app are right or not. Because I think It might not be an account issue but the app packaging or some thing like that.

Comment: This site is for programming questions only. You're asking programmers about an application update. That's like asking a taxi driver if he knows how to build a car. Voting to close as off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just submitted an app update on Saturday, but it wasn't until Monday that it was published - previously it took only a few hours. So, don't worry - it looks like app certification might have slowed down for some reason. If there's a problem with your submission, Microsoft will tell you.

Comment: Ya, I am waiting it to be passed. Thanx for clearing it to me :)